# How to connect to EC2 instance which is in Private subnet from my Windows OS client machine through Bastion host.?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-subnet, bastion-host

I have a scenario as following,
I have one EC2 instance in private subnet and one EC2 instance in public subnet.
How can I connect to private subnet EC2 instance through public subnet EC2 instance which is also called Bastion host (Jump box) from my Windows OS client machine.??

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Connect how, using ssh, a browser, or some other type of connection?

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect to the Bastion host, and use that connection to open a tunnel from your machine to the target machine in the private subnet. That allows you open a second connection to the target machine, using the tunnel.

Here is a guide on how to do this using Putty: [AWS Setup Bastion Host SSH Tunnel](https://medium.com/bizlab-technologies/aws-setup-bastion-host-ssh-tunnel-f5ec5cf10524#6759) (they are also opening a second tunnel to a Windows server, you can ignore that part).

Comment: Thanks Christian for the answer. I got the understanding and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is `in the bastion(public instance)`, make the copy of the `.pem` file that you assigned to `the private instance` when you launched it.

```
example.pem
```

Then, you need to make it only readable by you(otherwise you cannot make a connection).

```
chmod 400 example.pem
```

Finally, run this command below to connect to the private instance from the bastion. (Use the `private ip` of the `private instance` after `@` in the command below)

```
ssh -i "example.pem" ubuntu@10.0.2.254
```

That's it!!

Supplementally saying, the name of `.pem` file doesn't need to be the same as the one you assigned to `the private instance`. But the content which is `RSA PRIVATE KEY` must be the same as the one you assigned to `the private instance`.